# Why do I get exception in my own implementation of and function?

Tags: haskell, recursion, boolean

I'm trying to write my own `and` function in Haskell. It looks like:

```
and' :: [Bool] -> Bool
and' (x:xs) = x && and' xs
```

When I use `and' [True, True, True]` it gives me exception:

```
*** Exception: 6.hs:27:1-26: Non-exhaustive patterns in function and'
```

I figured out that adding: `and' _ = True` fixes my problem, but actually why do I have to add this line? If my way of thinking is correct function should return me `True && True && True` and when I use this combination in ghci it returns `True`. Could you explain me it please? Is there a way to see implementation of function `and` in ghci?

Comment: You did not take into account the case of an empty list. Since you each time recurse on the tail, eventually you will call `and' []`.

Comment: If you turn on warnings, GHC will point out that you missed the base case `[]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If my way of thinking is correct function should return me `True && True && True` and when I use this combination in `ghci` it returns `True`.

Your `and' [True, True, True]` will boil down to `True && True && True && and' []`. Since you did not write a clause for the empty list, it will thus fail. If there was a `False` in your list, then it would never really make that call to `and' []`, since `False && _` will return `False`, but a list that contains only `True`s will thus eventually make a call with the empty list.

You thus can fix the problem by handling the empty list case as well:

```
and' :: [Bool] -> Bool
and' [] = True
and' (x:xs) = x && and' xs
```

If you turn on the [**`-Wincomplete-patterns`** warning [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-patterns), it will list the patterns you did not implement.

Comment: “If you turn on the `-Wincomplete-patterns`...” – or, more sensibly, `-Wall`.